# How do you update a selected dropdown value using VBScript

Tags: html, .net, drop-down-menu, vbscript

I am trying to problematically change the dropdown selection on an InternetExplorer.Application then save that selection.  The code I have so far is

```
dim myValue
myValue="3"

for j = 0 to obj.Options.length - 1
    if(obj.Options(j).Value = myValue) then
        obj.Options(j).selected = true
        exit for
    end if
next
```

This works on the current pages dropdown list, however when I click save, the value "3" isn't saved and it reverts back to its original value when I reload the page.

Another thing to mention is that when I **manually** click the dropdown and select a value then save, it **does** update to the new value when I reload the page.  I have tried the obj.click function on it but I do not believe a programmatic mouse click works like a actual mouse click with the action listener.

My guess would be something to do with the databinding between the new value selection and the action listener for the page.  I am fairly new to vbscript and have tried all sorts of different things.

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thank You!

Comment: Please provide `html` code of how the dropdown box is defined on the web page and spread your `VBScript` code snippet to satisfy [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have the `obj` object set properly, e.g. something like 

`set obj = ie.document.getElementById("my_dropdown")` then you should ensure that *only one option is selected*:

```
for j = 0 to obj.Options.length - 1
    if (obj.Options(j).Value = myValue) then
        obj.Options(j).selected = true            ''' do not exit for
    else
        obj.Options(j).selected = false
    end if
next
```

or

```
For Each opt In obj.Options
    If opt.Value = myValue Then
        opt.Selected = True
    Else
        opt.Selected = False
    End If
Next
```

**Caution**: above code snippet could result to (undesired?) case that *no option remains selected*!

Comment: I just tried this and still no luck.  The value does change but the record doesn't save still.

Comment: I do not think that the FireEvent("onchange") is working.